# Shared(common) data storage and communication in android app

Tags: android, database, storage, communication, shared

Say we have an ongoing token number for queue which is to be shared(shown) among various users who have downloaded that particular app.

Question is:

1. Where should that common/shared token number be stored? Also which database should be used?
2. Does this require server setup? If yes, is there any alternative to that?
3. And how to make that token number accessible to various users of that app?

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need a server to deal with that.

If I were you I would work with Google Cloud. You can *very* easily integrate App Engine / Endpoints into your Android Apps if you use Android Studio.

1. Use Google Cloud [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/)
2. Use Google [Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/endpoints/add_module)
3. Share the token through an API of some description - any updates to users can be made real time using Cloud Messaging